# How to mock private method using JMockit by using withInstanceOf?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, stub, jmockit, stubbing

I needed to know that how to mock private method by using withInstanceOf in JMockit?
Here is the class I need to test.
package mockingPrivateMethodWithInstanceOf;

```
public class Simple
{
    private String iAmPrivate(String argString) 
    {
        return "Private Method";
    }
    public String publicCallsPrivate() 
    {
        String string = "aString";
        return iAmPrivate(string);
    }
}
```

Here is the test class

```
public class SimpleTest 
{    
    @Test 
    public void testPublicInvokesPrivate()
    {     
        final Simple simple =  new Simple();      
        new Expectations(simple)
        {
            {
                Deencapsulation.invoke(simple, "iAmPrivate", withInstanceOf(String.class));
                returns("Mocked method");
            }
        };
        assertEquals("Mocked method", simple.publicCallsPrivate());
    }   
}
```

When test class is executed it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid null value passed as argument 0
```

Comment: The method `withInstanceof(object)` always returns `null`, which is not accepted by `invoke(objectWithMethod, methodName, *nonNullArgs*)`. You will need to use some other argument matcher which returns a non-null value.

Comment: Thank you @Rogério May you please suggest any other argument matcher for doing this task.